# Android theming: Can I just set alpha value to an existing color?

Tags: android, theming

So if I'm defining a style for some widget and want to set text color to some predetermined color + some transparency.
Normally, I'd define it like this (oversimplified):

```
<item name="android:textColor">#a0ffffff</item>
```

However, I'd like to be able to do it like this:

```
<color name="textTitle">#ffffff</color>
<item name="android:textColor">#a0 | @color/textTitle</item>
<item name="android:someotherColor">#70 | @color/textTitle</item>
```

I'd like that `#a0` and `#70` to mean my desired transparency while the `@color...` represents some predefined color (which I may not know because it's ROM specific)

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: What minimum SDK level are you targeting?

Comment: Doesn't matter, really, I'll take any solution, but otherwise I'm targeting 8+

Comment: On API 21+ you can set alpha in color state list items, but that won't help much in earlier versions.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the color to @color/textTitle directly where you want to use it and use `android:alpha` to set the alpha value separately.

Comment: You mean on every widget where I want to use it? Maintenance heavy, but it could work.

Answer (score 1):

Support library has helper method `ColorUtils.setAlphaComponent(int color, int alpha)`.

Here is the source.

```
/**
 * Set the alpha component of {@code color} to be {@code alpha}.
 */
public static int setAlphaComponent(int color, int alpha) {
    if (alpha < 0 || alpha > 255) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("alpha must be between 0 and 255.");
    }
    return (color & 0x00ffffff) | (alpha << 24);
}
```